# Rename [decisiontrees] to [decision-tree]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499782/how-do-i-classify-this-value-using-a-decision-tree), I tried to change the tag from [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tree) to [decision-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decision-tree), but I got an error:

> You are attempting to create the tag [decision-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decision-tree); however the tag [decisiontrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decisiontrees) already exists!

I think [decision-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decision-tree) is a better tag than [decisiontrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decisiontrees), how can I change that?

Comment: A moderator must rename it.

Comment: @Robert: Does it really make sense to keep a synonym? Because if the original tag is completely removed, it should not be re-creatable.